# Insert Logging In Functions ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, logging, ascx

I have an .ascx containing javascript and div elements.

I want insert a log statement inside a function for troubleshooting.

May I know how can I achieve it?

Below is my code snippet:

```
function SaveGroupCheck() {
    var isValid = true;
    var haveError = false;

    var schedule = document.getElementById("<%=ddlExecutionSchedule.ClientID%>").value;

    //INSERT LOGGING HERE - Value of 'schedule'//

    if (schedule == "Weekly")
    {
        var xday = document.getElementById("<%=chkSelectDay.ClientID%>");
        var checkbox = xday.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var counter = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
            if (checkbox[i].checked) {
                counter++;
            }
        }

    //INSERT LOGGING HERE - Value of 'counter'//

        if (counter < 1) {
            $("#chkSelectDay").addClass('errorbox');
            $("#divSelectDay").addClass('has-error has-feedback');
            $("#lblSelectDay").addClass('has-error has-feedback');
        haveError = true;
        }
        else {
            $("#chkSelectDay").removeClass('errorbox');
            $("#divSelectDay").removeClass('has-error has-feedback');
            $("#lblSelectDay").removeClass('has-error has-feedback');
        }
    }

     //INSERT LOGGING HERE - Value of 'haveError'//
```

Below is a log which I attempted but failed. I will use a `try-catch` if the error info needs to be provided.

```
var logFileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logpath"] + "Debug_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_hhmmss") + ".log";
var itemPerPage = document.getElementById("<%=txtItemsPerPage.ClientID%>").value;
Log(DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_hhmmss") + " - itemPerPage = " + itemPerPage);

*logpath configured in app.config.
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To log any javascript variables you can use :

```
console.log("Hello I'm the variable value");
```

and open **chrome console** to see the value.

If you want to send variable value to server you must go to ajax call by calling server method for logging.

I hope that I understood your question.

Comment: If the page ran `__doPostBack()` before I entered chrome console, would the log still be there?

Comment: On page refresh, chrome console will be cleared, in your code you didn't mention anything regarding to postback, anyway try using alert() instead of console.log this will show dialog with value and it will prevent the postback until you click ok.